# Testing TypedArray recycle() does not throw RuntimeException

Tags: android, exception, android-resources, android-styles, typedarray

I tested `TypedArray` recycle with this code, expecting to get a runtime exception based on the documentation, but I did not get one.

> recycle
>
> added in API level 1
>   void recycle () Recycles the TypedArray, to be
>   re-used by a later caller. After calling this function you must not
>   ever touch the typed array again.
>
> Throws RuntimeException   if the TypedArray has already been recycled.

```
    public TimePickerPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TimePickerPreference, 0, 0);
        initTimePickerPreference(a);
        a.recycle();
    }
    protected void initTimePickerPreference(TypedArray a) {

        if (a != null)
            try {
                setTitle(a.getString(R.styleable.TimePickerPreference_android_title));
                mSummary = a.getString(R.styleable.TimePickerPreference_android_summary);
                mDefaultValue = a.getString(R.styleable.TimePickerPreference_android_defaultValue);
            } finally {
                a.recycle();
            }

    ...
    }
```

I traced the code with the Android Studio debugger and it went through both `a.recycle()` calls, while in *variables* pane `a` was not made `null`

The reason I made this test is because I was not 100% sure if it was OK to call `a.recycle()` in a different scope from where `a` was created.

I went further and duplicated the recycle call

```
    public TimePickerPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TimePickerPreference, 0, 0);
        initTimePickerPreference(a);
        a.recycle();
        a.recycle();
    }
    protected void initTimePickerPreference(TypedArray a) {

        if (a != null)
            try {
                setTitle(a.getString(R.styleable.TimePickerPreference_android_title));
                mSummary = a.getString(R.styleable.TimePickerPreference_android_summary);
                mDefaultValue = a.getString(R.styleable.TimePickerPreference_android_defaultValue);
            } finally {
                a.recycle();
                a.recycle();
            }

    ...
    }
```

Still no `RunTimeException`.

Is this a bug?
I ran it on AVD emulated device with Android IceCreamSandwich version (API 15).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.4_r1.2/android/content/res/TypedArray.java#TypedArray.recycle%28%29) the implementation of `TypedArray#recycle()` for API 15:

```
 public void recycle() {
     synchronized (mResources.mTmpValue) {
         TypedArray cached = mResources.mCachedStyledAttributes;
         if (cached == null || cached.mData.length < mData.length) {
             mXml = null;
             mResources.mCachedStyledAttributes = this;
         }
     }
 }
```

[Here's](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/content/res/TypedArray.java#1138) the implementation for API 25:

```
public void recycle() {
    if (mRecycled) {
        throw new RuntimeException(toString() + " recycled twice!");
    }
    mRecycled = true;
    // These may have been set by the client.
    mXml = null;
    mTheme = null;
    mAssets = null;
    mResources.mTypedArrayPool.release(this);
}
```

Obviously, docs state the implementation of the latest API, and you are running your app with API 15.

Comment: Just to make sure I will create a device for API26 and try it, although the documentation states it exists since API1

Comment: It exists from API 1, but the implementation has changed over time.

Comment: Confirmed! In API 26 the *RuntimeException recycled twice* does occur. It also confirms that the `TypedArray` can be recycled from a spawn method. I will not test it on every API to see when it started to comply, I simply don't want to install all APIs on my PC.